# Word Table Design shading and padding problems

Tags: microsoft-word

I am implementing a table design, but for some reason when I add paragraph before/after spacing I am getting whitespace where it should be shaded. This is after pasting plain text into the table. No matter what I do I cannot get the shading to fill the table cell correctly.

If I add a new table and use a banded row Table Design it works correctly when I change Paragraph formatting with before/after spacing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the cells that have this problem, or simply select the whole table

Right click and choose TABLE PROPERTIES from the popup menu (or use Table Properties button on the ribbon)

Go to CELL tab

Click OPTIONS button

Under Cell Margins, check the box for "Same as whole table"

Click OK